# How is the term "God" meant in the DC universe?

Tags: dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice, wonder-woman

In *Wonder Woman* movie, the term "God" is used for Zeus & Ares.

But in  the *Batman V Superman* movie, someone writes "False God" on the statue of Superman.

So kindly let me know what does the term 'GOD' mean in the DC universe.

Is any person who has any kind of superpower called GOD in DC universe?

Comment: Everything we see in the DC universe is a part of the Creation, which was created by [the Presence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presence_(DC_Comics)). He's the ultimate God, omnipotent, omniscient, and omnipresent (sometimes). All other "gods" (Old Gods - Zeus, etc; New Gods - Darkseid, All-Father) were created as the Source (the Presence's moniker) distributed energy.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> What is the term “God” meant to mean in the DC universe?

Exactly what it means in *this* universe...someone/thing/power who is **worshipped** as a "God".

The only difference is that in the DC Universe (and Marvel Universe for that matter) is that some "Gods" are **real**.

**What** they are is unclear or rarely explored or just waved away. In the MCU for instance, "Gods" such as Asgardians are treated as *more advanced aliens* who were revered and worshipped as gods by more primitive man.

**The issue of actual "divinity" is essentially ignored.**

In the DCU this has not really been explored yet but at the moment, the Athenian gods referenced appear to be beings of great power and abilities. Whether they have any *divinity* is a matter of interpretation and faith.

The reference to "False God" in BvS was to highlight that the common folk were starting to worship Superman as a 'saviour' type character even though he would be the first to state that he is not a god.

So, just having enormous power (super or otherwise) does not make you a god but it might get you worshipped as one.

Answer (score 6):

By definition, **God** is

> 1. (in Christianity and other monotheistic religions) the creator and ruler of the universe and source of all moral authority; the supreme being.
> 2. (in certain other religions) a superhuman being or spirit worshipped as having power over nature or human fortunes; a deity.

In WonderWoman, Zeus and Ares are gods from Greek mythology, superhuman beings with power over us.

When Superman arrived on Earth, he was also hailed as a God, someone who would protect us and redeem us. However, those who didn't trust SuperMan claimed he was just nothing but a false God, **he would not bring salvation or redemption to us**.

Answer (score 4):

**More or less any character that is an immortal being with superpowers**

By immortal, I mean someone who cannot be killed by human means for example :

Wonder woman spoiler :

> Ares is immortal but dies to Diana's ability as a demi-god

Possible DCEU / Confirmed *Batman The dark knight* returns spoiler :

> Superman is indestructible, survives a nuclear strike at point blank but dies to some amount of Kryptonite as can be seen in this scene of [Superman surviving the nuke in Dark Knight returns](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fo6ouf2onWs)

In conclusion, any **humanoid-like life form possessing powers and durability that defies humans understanding** is considered a God.

Edit: This power will bring people to worship them as any regular gods as Paulie_D and BlueMoon93 pointed out

Edit2: Ares doesn't indeed die to Diana's sword (Paulie_D), my bad for misremembering it. The magic sword is able to kill gods tho (and cut absolutely anything in the entire universe as a matter of fact)

Comment: Ares was **not** killed by a magic sword.

Comment: SPOILER ALERT : In the movie the magic sword was destroyed really easily though

Comment: Yeah, that looked more of plot device than anything else to me. In the comics, Diana's blade is able to cut Superman just from touching it and she says it can cut electrons off atoms (so there is nothing in the universe this blade can't cut except atoms themselves (maybe ?))

Comment: @LiquidSame Yes, Diana's sword is one of the strongest objects/weapons in the universe and is referred to as indestructible a few times, as I recall. Either the sword in the movie was a different one or they took some liberty from the comics (as was their prerogative).