# Did Wonder Woman kill Ares?

Tags: character, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman

In the conflict scene between Wonder Woman and Ares we are left feeling that she has defeated him. However, all we really know is that Ares is no longer around and there is a rather large crater where he used to be.

But, Ares is supposedly immortal, you don't just *kill* an immortal being. Also, he is supposed to be a major adversary of Wonder Woman's.

Killing him off in the first WW movie seems silly.

**So my question is, did Wonder Woman defeat Ares by killing him or did she simply send him away momentarily?**

Comment: Well, Circe was supposed to be a major WW villain. Still, they stated all other gods are dead.

Comment: She definitely defeated him. Whether ***she killed him*** would be a worthwhile question.

Comment: @Ghoti, my wording could've been better. Changed.

Comment: To quote Tom Holt "The best definition of an immortal is someone who hasn't died yet"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But, Ares is supposedly immortal, you don't just kill an immortal being.

Of course you can... Zeus is dead as are the other gods<sup>*</sup> (killed by Ares)... **at least as far as we know...**

Thus, so far, we know that "immortal" does not mean "unkillable" in the DCEU.

> Some fictional beings are completely immortal (or very nearly so) in that they are immune to death by injury, disease and age. Sometimes such powerful immortals can only be killed by each other.
>
> <sup>[Immortality in Fiction - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immortality_in_fiction)</sup>

So we've established that a "god" or "demigod" can kill another god... in fact, **that's the entire reason Diana was created.**

Diana takes Ares' assault (the lightning) and blows a hole right through him.

[image]

> Is Ares dead?

## Yes..<sup>*</sup>

<sup>* Until they decide they want him back</sup>

Comment: So then what does *mortal* and *immortal* mean in the dc comic universe?

Comment: That's another question...but immortal does not mean exactly *unkillable* (at least as far as we know). You might ask what a "god" is [but someone already did](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75849/how-is-the-term-god-meant-in-the-dc-universe)

Comment: Fair enough, That is a good question, too. I know more about actual Greek mythology than I do about the DC universe.

Comment: Edited to include the immortality vs unkillable bit..which is a good point to mention. Thanks.

Comment: @Octopus The most common sense in immortality is that the person cannot die by normal means. (aging, diseases, and any other added rule). But usually they may die if killed correctly.

Comment: @Octopus For example: in the famous immortals story: Highlander, the immortals couldn't die by any other method, unless beheaded.